# How to tell search engines about localized versions of the website when using Firebase Hosting i18n rewrites?

Tags: firebase, internationalization, seo, firebase-hosting

Firebase has recently [announced](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/firebase-hosting-new-features.html) support for the [i18n rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites) feature. It allows you to serve different content depending on a user's country or preferred language.

But since the different versions of the content are served under *the same* URL, a search engine crawler will only be able to find one version of localized content.

Without i18n rewrites, I would need to create a root page that redirects to localized ones depending on the user's language preference or location (`myapp.com` redirects either to `myapp.com/en/` or `myapp.com/fr/`). With that approach, crawlers could easily find and index all localized versions of my website.

But how can I achieve that discoverability with i18n rewrites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a combination of `<link rel="alternate">` and `<link rel="canonical">` for this. Firebase Hosting will still serve your localized content from the full path (e.g. if your `root` is `/intl` and someone visits `/intl/fr` they will see the French content regardless of headers and cookies).

The Google crawler will use local IPs from a variety of countries but *no Accept-Language* header when crawling ([source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6144055?hl=en)). So my recommendation would be:

1. In all of your pages, add `<link rel="alternate" langhref="{lang}" href="{url}">` tags for each localized version, where `{url}` is the absolute URL to the localized version (e.g. `/intl/fr/about.html`).
2. In all of your localized pages, add a `<link rel="canonical" href="{url}">` that points to the full localized version. (see [Google guidance](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077))

With those tags in place, Google should be able to discover the multi-language and multi-locale content in your site.

Comment: Is there a way to perform an i18n redirect instead of an i18n rewrite?

Comment: Not presently, if it's something you'd like to see please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) so we can track interest.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Are there by now any plans for adding support for i18n redirects? Notably, the Google Search Central explicitly recommends using separate URLs for different language versions of a page (https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites). Is that still not possible using Firebase Hosting?

Comment: Yes, very important to have it as redirects instead of rewrites. It looks like a blocker to us to adopt Firebase Hosting